Optimizing Infinite Scroll Caching in Next.js with SSR Data Fetching
I’m building an app in NextJs with infinite scroll functionality, where data is loaded server-side and cached for faster performance. The initial data is fetched and loaded from the cache, but I'm struggling with caching the new pages as the user scrolls. Currently, I send a limit to the Backend to fetch data up to the current scroll page, but I’m unsure how to save these new pages to the cache without losing to much performance.
What is the best approach to dynamically cache additional pages as they are loaded, ensuring smooth performance and avoiding unnecessary server load? Any suggestions for optimizing this caching strategy would be greatly appreciated!

Are you using fetch with {next: {revalidate: <cache timeout>}} ?

Yes I am using fetch. And than I have an infinite scroll where I load the next pages. But these new pages I load are not saved in the cache. Only the first page is loaded.

Can you add a few example URLs you're using for the initial fetch and the subsequent fetches along with some code to your question so we can try to reproduce this? BR
